# thread::sleep is required for my toast notification program in Rust/WinRT

Tags: windows, rust, windows-runtime

I'm new to WinRT. I wrote a Rust/WinRT code to push a toast notification on Win10. My code seems to work correctly, but I have 2 questions about Rust/WinRT.

Here is my code.

```rust
winrt::import!(
    dependencies
        os
    types
        windows::ui::notifications::*
);

use windows::ui::notifications::{
    ToastNotificationManager, ToastTemplateType, ToastNotification,
};

fn main() -> winrt::Result<()> {
    let notification = {
        let toast_xml = ToastNotificationManager::get_template_content(ToastTemplateType::ToastText01)?;

        let text_node = toast_xml.get_elements_by_tag_name("text")?.item(0)?;
        let text = toast_xml.create_text_node("Hello from Rust/WinRT!")?;
        text_node.append_child(text)?;

        ToastNotification::create_toast_notification(toast_xml)?
    };
    
    ToastNotificationManager::get_default()?
        .create_toast_notifier_with_id("{1AC14E77-02E7-4E5D-B744-2EB1AE5198B7}\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe")?
        .show(notification)?;

    std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_millis(10));
    Ok(())
}
```

It works as I expected, but I have 2 questions.

1. `text_node` is immutable. However, my code seems to change them. Why isn't mutability required? (That is, why does not `windows::data::xml::dom::IXmlNode::append_child(&self, new_child: __0)` require `&mut self`?)
2. If I remove `thread::sleep`, then this program ends without pushing the toast notification. Why? The [JavaScript example in MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.notifications.toastnotification?view=winrt-19041) does not require it.

Note that I use Win10 Pro v1909 build 18363.778, Rust 1.44.0 stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc, and winrt 0.7.0.